# How can I create dummy variables from a numeric variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

How can I create dummy variables from a numeric variable in R?
I want to create N dummy variables. In such a way the numeric variable means how many zeros will come, counting from the first column. Imagine N=6. Like this:

```
   x
a  5
b  2
c  4
d  1
e  9
```

It must become:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6
a  0 0 0 0 0 1
b  0 0 1 1 1 1
c  0 0 0 0 1 1
d  0 1 1 1 1 1
e  0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's your data based on? What's deciding if its a 1 or 0?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky solution for you

```
x = c(5,2,4,1,9)
N = 6
out = matrix(1, length(x), N)

for (i in 1:length(x))
    out[i,1:min(x[i], N)] = 0

> out
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in a `vectorize`d manner by creating `row/column` index and assigning an already created `matrix` of 1s to 0 based on the index

```
m1 <- matrix(1, ncol = N, nrow = length(x), 
       dimnames = list(letters[seq_along(x)], seq_len(N)))
x1 <- pmin(x, ncol(m1))
m1[cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(m1)), x1), sequence(x1))] <- 0
m1
#  1 2 3 4 5 6
#a 0 0 0 0 0 1
#b 0 0 1 1 1 1
#c 0 0 0 0 1 1
#d 0 1 1 1 1 1
#e 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
x <- c(5,2,4,1,9)
N <- 6
```